# How to get first day year dynamically as value to parameter in ssis package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need first day of year as parameter value
Brief explanation:
 I have an sql query command like this written in ssis OLE DB source

```
SELECT  [StudentID]
      ,[StudentName]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[DepartmentID]
  FROM [Student].[dbo].[StudentPrimaryDetails] where StartDate = ?
```

results

```
 StudentID  StudentName StartDate   EndDate DepartmentID
    1   Shah    Jan  1 2014 12:00AM NULL    1
    2   Sumitra Jan  1 2014 12:00AM NULL    1
    3   Sumathi Jan  1 2015 12:00AM NULL    2
    4   Avinash Jan  1 2016 12:00AM NULL    3
    5   subbu   Jan  1 2015 12:00AM NULL    4
    6   Venky   Jan  1 2015 12:00AM NULL    1
    7   Akash   Jan  1 2015 12:00AM NULL    2
```

I added date parameter in SSIS
Name as Startdate and datetype as datetime and value as 2015-01-01

But instead of hard code value in date parameter i need to pass dynamic values and get first day of every year to that I remove hard code and run package whenever I need without changing anything in package.Please help me from this.

Answer (score 1):

Below query will give start date of current year :

```
 SELECT        DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Entire query as per your need :

```
SELECT  [StudentID]
      ,[StudentName]
      ,[StartDate]
      ,[EndDate]
      ,[DepartmentID]
  FROM [Student].[dbo].[StudentPrimaryDetails] where StartDate = (
SELECT        DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply I had already tried that but I don't want to add query in sql command Instead I have parameter in ssis package .I had to add value dynamically for the paramater.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked about 4 years ago but I came across similar issue recently. Here is how I handled it:
First I created String variable at the Package level. 
Then I used a Derived Column to cast the String to DB_DateTime.

[image: PackageVariable]

[image: Derived Column Transformation]

I hope this helps anyone having similar issues.